# Remote ASP.Net LOGIN WebPage in Winforms APP

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, security

I have a Win form Application Thats using ASMX webservice and displaying information , 
i am using Custom Usernames passwords in SQLSERVER , all connection  done by asmx webservice.

Now i want to Show a ASP.NET web page that actually displays the SWF (FLashPlayer , Live Stream) . and open in my Winform application .

the page is Hosted on my IIS and can be customized in anyway ,

**What is the best approach to Secure it that its only open in my application and user cant open it via other browsers.**

Comment: Do you have to use asp.net page? You can also embed swf in winform directly.

Comment: i am using the jwPlayer , do you mean i can embed the jwplayer swf file in my winform Application ? and can use it ?

Comment: You can create dynamic html string with jwPlayer tags and video url and set that to webbrowser control. Check this [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5568321/125551) and [Microsoft Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx)

Comment: my App is a click once App , if i store swf in my app , then the user can copy it or if i post it on server and use its link then still user can access it .